# Stopping Pandoc from escaping urls when converting from markdown

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I have the following markdown:

```
[title]({{url}})
```

The `{{url}}` is needed for templating purposes later, after markdown is parsed to html.

Pandoc outputs:

```html
<a href="%7B%7Burl%7D%7D">title</a>
```

but I need:

```html
<a href="{{ur}}">title</a>
```

Is there an option in Pandoc to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL encoding happens during the Markdown parsing step. We can revert it with the help of a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters): Save the below to a file `urldecode.lua` and pass that file to pandoc via `--lua-filter=urldecode.lua`.

```lua
local hexchar = function(x)
  return string.char(tonumber(x, 16))
end

function Link (link)
  link.target = link.target:gsub('%%(%x%x)', hexchar)
  return link
end
```